# Connecting android app with Wordpress site

Tags: java, android

Hello i started working on my first android app  for a Lifestyle magazine,The site is already build in Wordpress . The main question is :
1. Is there any way to connect an android app with Site so when an admin puts a text on site ,the text publish too on the android app ?
2.How to update information on published android app on app store ?

Comment: You have to connect your site via rest web services.

On the Site side -
Wordpress plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/ to enable rest api from the site.(Guide with testing examples)

On the Android app side - 
Retrofit -http://retrofit/  Very good open source library to pass json over http in android. (Guide)

Or you can use Volley as well in android side.

Answer (score 2):

you can go with web view in android [try web view](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps#alternatives)

One way to get information from your website to your android application would be to set up a RESTful service with your website. From there you can read, insert, update information via HTTP.

**for WordPress, you can use this plugin for REST-API [JSON API USER](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/)**

or download this and use [WP RESTAPI](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API)